# Get all payment transactions recursively using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a series of records. Based on the data below, how to get all transaction (XZ) for specific customer invoice (XR)?

**Legend**

```
XR - customer invoice
XZ - payments
XA - manual clearing
```

**Example 1**

```
Doc Nos      Type   TY    Amount     Cleared Doc
9500011864   A121   XR    36247.62   9000001660
9600009487   A121   XZ       -4.76   9000001660
9000001660   A121   XA    36242.86   9600012264
9600012264   A121   XZ   -72490.48   9600012264
```

**Condition**

```
Doc Nos : 9500011864
TY      : XR
```

**Desired output**

```
Doc Nos      Type   TY    Amount     Cleared Doc
9600009487   A121   XZ       -4.76   9000001660
9600012264   A121   XZ   -72490.48   9600012264
```

Explanation above: There is Customer invoice (XR) with the amount of 36,247.62. There is payment recorded (XZ) with the value of 4.76 for document nos (9500011864). Since this is partial payment, there is a manual clearing balance (XA) with the amount of 36,242.86. Another Payment is posted (XZ) with the amount of 72,490.48 referring to document nos (9000001660).

**Example 2**

```
Doc Nos      Type   TY    Amount     Cleared Doc
9500011864   A121   XR    36247.62   9000001660
9600009487   A121   XZ       -4.76   9000001660
9000001660   A121   XA    36242.86   9000001661
9000001661   A121   XZ       -2.86   9000001661
9000001661   A121   XA    36240.00   9600012264
9600012264   A121   XZ   -36240.00   9600012264
```

**Condition**

```
Doc Nos : 9500011864
TY      : XR
```

**Desired output**

```
Doc Nos      Type   TY    Amount     Cleared Doc
9600009487   A121   XZ       -4.76   9000001660
9000001661   A121   XZ       -2.86   9000001661
9600012264   A121   XZ   -36240.00   9600012264
```

**Example 3**

```
Doc Nos      Type   TY    Amount     Cleared Doc
9500000368   A121   XR    36247.62   9000000022
9000000022   A121   XA   -36247.62   9000000022
9000000022   A121   XA    36247.62   9000000022
9600016951   A121   XZ   -36247.62   9000000022
```

**Condition**

```
Doc Nos : 9500000368
TY      : XR
```

**Desired output**

```
Doc Nos      Type   TY    Amount     Cleared Doc
9600016951   A121   XZ   -36247.62   9000000022
```

How can I do this using SQL Server 2016? Is CTE Recursive applicable on this?

Comment: 1) For Example 1 . what is the relation between the two desired records  `9600009487` & `9600012264` while the condition is `9500011864` only ? ........ 2 ) what is the issue for using `where TY = 'XZ'` ?

Comment: based on your given scenario's:

you are just doing this ---> select * from table where [TY] = 'XZ' 

hope this might help.

Comment: This is recursive process. Their relationship is based on clearing documents. XR clearing doc to XZ clearing doc, as well as XA clearing doc  to XZ clearing doc. If partial payment (XZ) Clearing doc to (XA) document nos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a recursive query. You select the XR record for the given "Doc Nos". With its "Cleared Doc" you find related records (where "related" means they have this number in either "Doc Nos" or "Cleared Doc" depending on their `TY`). With all thus found records, you do the same with their "Cleared Doc", etc. At last you show all XZ records from the found rows.

```
with cte(doc_nos, type, ty, amount, cleared_doc) as
(
  select doc_nos, type, ty, amount, cleared_doc
  from mytable 
  where doc_nos = 9500011864 and ty = 'XR'
  union all
  select t.doc_nos, t.type, t.ty, t.amount, t.cleared_doc
  from cte 
  join mytable t on (cte.ty = 'XR' and t.ty = 'XZ' and cte.cleared_doc = t.cleared_doc)
                 or (cte.ty = 'XR' and t.ty = 'XA' and cte.cleared_doc = t.doc_nos)
                 or (cte.ty = 'XA' and t.ty = 'XZ' and cte.cleared_doc = t.doc_nos)
)
select *
from cte
where ty = 'XZ';
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your seniors , what you said

> XR clearing doc to XZ clearing doc, as well as XA clearing doc to XZ
>   clearing doc

and the conditions should be for `Doc Nos` & `TY`

Hope this help:-

```
Select * from table
where TY = ( Get the TY value here based on conditions of Doc Nos & TY )
```

**Demo:-**

```
Create table MyTable (Doc_Nos varchar(20) , [type] varchar (10) , TY char (2) , Amount Decimal (18,2) , Cleared_Doc varchar(20))
go
insert into MyTable values ('9500011864' , 'A121' , 'XR' , 36247.62 , '9000001660' )
insert into MyTable values ('9600009487' , 'A121' , 'XZ' , -4.76 , '9000001660' )
insert into MyTable values ('9000001660' , 'A121' , 'XA' , 36242.86 , '9600012264' )
insert into MyTable values ('9600012264' , 'A121' , 'XZ' , -72490.48 , '9600012264' )
go

declare
        @sDocNos varchar(20),
        @TY     char (2)

select 
        @sDocNos = '9500011864' ,
        @TY      ='XR'

Select * from MyTable
where TY = (
            select TY 
            from MyTable 
            where Cleared_Doc = (
                select Cleared_Doc 
                from MyTable 
                where Doc_Nos = @sDocNos 
                and TY = @TY ) and TY = 'XZ')
```

**Result:-**

[image]